# How does adding a capacitor change the frequency response of this inductive LPF?

Tags: capacitor, inductor, low-pass, load

I know that a simple circuit like this in an ideal case will have a frequency response of a single pole LPF, where the cutoff frequency is given by:

[image]

cutoffFreq = 1/(twoPi*L*2R)

This is reviewed [here](http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Courses/ee1.cct/circuit-theory/section8/lowpass.html).

But what would the frequency response look like if you add a capacitor in parallel to the inductor like this:

[image]

Would it still be a low pass filter? What would it look like? How would it change based on the capacitance?

I tried running this on circuitlab for simulation but it is giving me an error and I don't know why:

[image]

It gives info on this error here but I don't understand it: https://www.circuitlab.com/docs/faq/#q_bode_opsolve_failed

No matter what I do it won't simulate with the inductor in there. But if I replace it with a capacitor it will simulate. Is there something else I'm supposed to be doing?

If it's not hard, what would be the transfer function of this circuit? Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend downloading the free [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) and play around

Comment: Regarding the transfer function: give it a try yourself first as you learn the best by trying. Edit your question to show your approach and people will be happy to help you along.

Comment: You need to specify the input and output signals. It matters.

Comment: @Huisman I tried running it on circuitlab.com but it's giving me an error. Do you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: It becomes a notch filter.

Answer (score 1):

Well looks like I was able to get it running on https://www.falstad.com/afilter/

Looks like the capacitor turns it into a notch filter. Kind of interesting.[image]